# webshim fails to grab the Spanish locale

Tags: webshim

In firefox webshim fail to grab spanish locale, it always show in english but for example en fr it works fine and show france.

How can fix it?
I want my application to locale browser adpate.

Answer (score 0):

I dowload:
https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/master/js-webshim/minified/shims/i18n/formcfg-es.js

and add code at my html.

```
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.15.7/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <!-- polyfiller file to detect and load polyfills -->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.15.7/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../resources/js/formcfg-es.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/formcfg-es.js}"></script>
    <script>
      //webshim.setOptions('forms', { addValidators: true });
      webshim.setOptions('forms', {
          replaceValidationUI: true,
            lazyCustomMessages: true,
            addValidators: true,
            overrideMessages: true
        });
      webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);
      webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
      webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
    </script>
```

and add the sentences are missing in spanish version.